# Filling GridView Based on DropDownList selected Value (vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a drop down list that has inventory material groups, and I would like there to be a way that when I select a different group, the grid view loads the materials for that group. I'm a little confused on how to accomplish this...

ASPX

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$            ConnectionStrings:Design_Construction_V2ConnectionString %>"      ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Design_Construction_V2ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [UnitPriceInfo], [groupNumber], [itemDescription], [CrossTieType], [AFEFunctionCode], [AFECode], [unitType], [unitPrice] FROM [itemsList_]" FilterExpression="groupNumber = {0}">
    <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="groupNumber" ControlID="ddlMaterials" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="" />
    </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlMaterials"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display.">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPriceInfo" HeaderText="UnitPriceInfo" SortExpression="UnitPriceInfo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="groupNumber" HeaderText="groupNumber" SortExpression="groupNumber" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="itemDescription" HeaderText="itemDescription" SortExpression="itemDescription" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CrossTieType" HeaderText="CrossTieType" SortExpression="CrossTieType" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AFEFunctionCode" HeaderText="AFEFunctionCode" SortExpression="AFEFunctionCode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AFECode" HeaderText="AFECode" SortExpression="AFECode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="unitType" HeaderText="unitType" SortExpression="unitType" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="unitPrice" HeaderText="unitPrice" SortExpression="unitPrice" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

CODEBEHIND

```
 Private Sub ddlMaterials_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlMaterials.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim db As New DesignConstructionDataContext

        Dim materials = (From m In db.Estimate_Groups
                     Where (m.BigGroup = "Materials")
                     Select m.groupName)

        ddlMaterials.DataSource = materials
        ddlMaterials.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ddlMaterials_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ddlMaterials.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `FilterParameters` to `SelectParameters`. In where clause use this - `where groupNumber = @groupNumber`. So changed aspx will be like following.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$            ConnectionStrings:Design_Construction_V2ConnectionString %>"      ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Design_Construction_V2ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [UnitPriceInfo], [groupNumber], [itemDescription], [CrossTieType], [AFEFunctionCode], [AFECode], [unitType], [unitPrice] FROM [itemsList_] where groupNumber = @groupNumber">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter Name="groupNumber" ControlID="ddlMaterials" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```